# opening .ts files in C and reading bit by bit the contents of the stream file

Tags: c, transport-stream

Can a mpeg 2 transport stream ( .ts ) file be opened in binary mode in C ?? How to read the contents of the file bit by bit for analyzing the various tables in the transport stream?

Answer (score 0):

Read the data as byte and use shift operation to convert the BYTE to bit.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple in belows 2 steps. But i guess to use this info you need to understand the file format of mpeg 2 transport stream ( .ts ).

1> you can open file with `rb` mode

2> Now read byte from file.

3> Now get desigred bit from that byte as follows

```
bit = Read_byte & (1 << position_of_bit);
```

here position of bit is the position of bit starting from 0 to LSB.